# Candy Picking Simulation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I want to create a simulation. It will be like: A bowl of candy and a tong. the thong will dive in and will pick one of the candies. I want candies to collide with tongs physic etc.

How can I achieve something like this?

Here is what i'm thinking:
For the scene:

**Bowl**: Rigidbody (Passive)
**Candies**: (Particles + molecular script)
**Tong**: Rigidbody (Active) + Collison

For the animation: Just right one of the candies and parent it to the tong?

I don't know I might be wrong. Any help would be helpful. Or is there any other way to achieve this kind of animation?

Found a photo basically would be something like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future reference, you can paste your images into the post itself rather than as a link. This improves readability and makes your question easier to answer.

Comment: You already seem to have a decent Idea of how to start. Why not give it a go and ask questions if you encounter issues and get stuck?

Comment: Shouldn't a few particles be rigid bodies so you actually can move and grab them? (I am not sure if the grab will work without further adjustments.)

Comment: I also would use a simple rig to animate the tong. Then add a collision modifier. I still don't think you can grab particles (candy). But honestly, I never tried the molecular add-on. I would make the candy (or just a part of them) a rigid body, cloth, or soft body to get the physic simulated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example with two ***Cloth* simulations**. A *Soft Body* simulation and *Rigid Body* simulation should work, too. The physic settings for *Rigid Body* are a bit different.

[image: picking candy animation]

You need the following:

1. a **bowl** object with *Collision* modifier
2. a rigged **tong** with a *Collision* modifier. With the *Skin* modifier you can create a simple tong mesh and armature quickly. Just extrude 4 vertices, and mirror them. Extrude the root, and create the armature with the *Skin* modifier button. Rename the bones and add a postfix (*.L/.R*) so you can mirror and symmetrize them. Apply the skin modifier and bind the mesh to the armature with automatic weights.
3. optional, a bunch of **static candy (the white ones)**. Use your favorite physic sim or particles to fill the bowl. Apply modifier/transformation so it's static.
4. more **sweets with a *Cloth* simulation (yellow ones)**. When you have candies of different colors and shapes it might be a good idea to join them into different objects (making groups) and add a *Cloth* modifier to each candy object. Enable *Collision* and *Self Collision* for the *Cloth* and add a *Collision* modifier.
5. the **chosen candy that you want to pick (the red one)**. Add a *Vertex Weight Edit* modifier, a *Cloth* modifier, and a *Collision* modifier. Also, add a *Child Of* object constraint and choose one of the tip bones as target.

**Settings:**

- enable *Pressure* for the *Cloth* to make the candy a little more rigid (red one in the example) -or- enable *Internal Springs* if you like them more squishy like gums (yellow ones in the example)
- adjust the *Collision Distance* value in the *Cloth* settings so it fits your object sizes.
- for the chosen candy create an empty Vertex Group and add it to the *Pin Group* in the *Cloth* settings. The *Pin* group is needed to grab the candy.

**Simulation and Animation**

The first 149 frames are just for the *Cloth* simulation so it can scatter the yellow spheres and they settle down.

For the red candy, the weight for the *Pin* group and the *Influence* value of the *Child Of* constraint are set to 0 for these first 149 frames. The weight is controlled by the *Default Value* of the *Vertex Weight Edit* modifier. The *Pin* weight is basically the switch between simulated and animated. With a *Pin* weight of 0 the *Cloth* simulation controls it. A weight of 1 pins the object and you can keyframe its position or let its parent control its position.

[image: settle down]

To grab the candy you need to do three things:

1. set the weight of the *Pin* vertex group to 1 by setting the *Default Value* of the *Vertex Weight Edit* modifier to 1. The *Cloth* simulation no longer controls the object and you can animate it now.
2. set *Influence* of the *Child Of* modifier to 1 so that the picked candy becomes a child of the tong's tip bone.
3. move the picked candy to the simulated position → keyframe its position. The *Cloth* simulation only moves the mesh and leaves the object's position untouched. Watch the origin (orange dot) the example animation. When you "pin" the object in step 1, the mesh is reset to it's original position and "teleports" the candy back.

   To get the exact position, copy of the simulated candy. Rename the objects. The copy becomes the new original and the old one will be a helper object. Apply the cloth modifier of the simulated candy (=now helper object). Then run the simulation again, and go to the desired frame. Now move the candy to the helper object (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and keyframe its position.

Note: there are two keyframes at frame 1 and frame 149 to keep the values constantly at 0 (=sim phase). Frame 150 and 179 keep the values at 1 (=grab & drag animation), and frame 180 sets them back to 0 (=drop the candy). Alternatively, set the *Interpolation Type* to *Constant* in the *Graph Editor*.

[image: pick the candy]

To drop the candy just do step 1 and 2 from above with 0 values. That is, set the weight of the *Pin* group and the *Influence* of the *Child Of* modifier to 0, and the physic simulation will make it drop.

A *Rigid Body Simulation* works the same, except that you need no *Pin* group, no *Collision* modifiers. Keyframe the *Animated* checkbox to switch between simulation and animation. The tong must be a passive rigid body and *Deform* must be enabled.

Comment: Wow! You are amazing Blunder! Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Great answer ‼️